# Does "No Spring Framework or similar" exclude the use of Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am working on a beginner task in Java. But I am uncertain whether to use Spring Boot or not. No Spring Framework or similar is desired. I've read many articles about the difference, but I am still unsure. Is Spring Boot a technical "subset" of Spring Framework, so that no use of Spring Framework excludes the use of Spring Boot?
Thanks for help.

Comment: "No Spring Framework or similar is required." by whom? You should ask *them* whether they would consider spring boot fair game. (I guess they wouldn't)

Comment: Sorry I meant  "No Spring Framework or similar is desired"!!

Comment: I asked them but I've been told that I have to find out whether it excludes Spring Boot or not. So here I am.

Comment: Out of curiosity, who are they and why do they have a problem with spring? Anyway yes, spring boot is part of the spring framework.

Comment: See [here](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot). Money quote (emphasis mine): "*Spring Boot makes it easy to create stand-alone, production-grade **Spring based Applications** that you can "just run".*"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Spring Boot is a part of the Spring Framework.

it provides (amongst others) features for easing configuration, running an app server and some structures for your project.

You may not need all that in a beginner Java task.
Instead you may create a default java project and add your required dependencies as you need them.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework#Spring_Boot